# Trouble with L'Hôpital Justification for Complicated Limit of Integral

Tags: integration, limits

Suppose we want to prove $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow\infty} x(t)=0$ where $x(t)=e^{-at}\int_{t_0}^{t}e^{as}r(s)ds+C$, $a>0$ and $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow\infty} r(t)=0$.

I first did $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow\infty} x(t)=\dfrac{\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow\infty} \int_{t_0}^{t}e^{as}r(s)ds+C}{\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow\infty}e^{at}}=\dfrac{\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow\infty} \int_{t_0}^{t}e^{as}r(s)ds}{\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow\infty}e^{at}}$ and tried to use L'Hôpital but am having trouble. I know that the denominator goes to $\infty$ but how to do the top? If I can get the top to go to $\infty$ then applying L'Hôpital would give me the desired result. Any help please?

Comment: In order to apply L'Hopital we need only that the denominator is divergent.

Comment: What are conditions on $a$? Positive real?

Comment: @A.Γ. Yes, $a>0$

Comment: @RobertZ Hm, why is that? I thought both the numerator and denominator have to either go to $\infty$ or $0$

Comment: See the note at the end of the proof: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_proof

Comment: @RobertZ Interesting, thank you!